# Как удалить ветку на сервере?

Tags: git

Я создал ветку на сервере `release-1.0`

Вот так выглядит

```
aleksey@aleksey:~/Downloads/NTZ/FittingRoom$ git branch -a
* develop
release-1.0
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/develop
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/release-1.0
```

Теперь я сделал мерж с мастером и хочу ее удалить, пишу такую команду

```
$ git branch -d origin/release-1.0
```

и мне показывает, что такой ветки нет...

И вот, что еще интересно, когда я сделал мерж этой удаленой ветки релиз и удаленой ветки мастер, все прошло успешно и я еще `tag` повесил на нее...

Потом переключался с ветки на ветку и вернулся обратно на удаленый мастер, а там нет этого последнего мержа... Странно...

Comment: Без `origin/`, `git branch -d release-1.0`

Comment: Так если я так сделаю, то удалится ветка локальная... А мне нужно удаленную убрать...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[начиная с версии 1.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/4827341) вы можете удалить `ветку` в удалённом (тавтология, да) хранилище (например, `origin`) с помощью:

```
$ git push origin --delete ветка
```

что, вероятно, несколько легче запомнить, чем «старый» формат:

```
$ git push origin :ветка
```

Comment: ...в котором есть смысл, если знать, что это `сервер что:куда`, где `что` может быть "ничем". Но новая форма определённо понятнее, да.

Comment: @D-side а мне нравится старая форма. Запушить "ничего" в ветку.